# how do i dispose of a class that is a property of another class?

Tags: c#

How do I dispose of DC in this situation where DC is a property of Service class?

```
 class Service()

  {

     public DataContext DC= new DataContext();

     public void SomeMethod()
       {   
          DC is used here.

       }

     public void SomeOtherMethod()
       {
          DC is also used here.
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "Service" class should implement IDisposable if it maintains references to unmanaged resources.  This tells clients of your class that they need to call Dispose() on instances of "Service".  You can call Dispose() on "DC" in your class' Dispose() method.

```
class Service : IDisposable
{
    public DataContext DC= new DataContext();

    public void Dispose( )
    {
        DC.Dispose( );
    }
}
```

As an aside, I would avoid creating public fields in C# where properties are the common idiom.

Comment: what about the instance of Service itself? Do I need to add more to the Dispose method or does the GC act as usual?

Comment: The garbage collector is perfectly capable of handling your managed class, you just need to call dispose to clean up any unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1):

Make your Service IDisposable and dispose the DataContext in the Dispose method. It is a common pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) on your hosting class and dispose of the hosted DC in the Dispose() method. Then use the hosting class using 'using'..

```
using(Service service = new Service())
{
    // do something with "service" here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Service class should take care of disposing DataContext.

Use the standard [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Implement IDisposable:
[MSDN: Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

```
public void Dispose() 
{
    Dispose(true);

    // Use SupressFinalize in case a subclass
    // of this type implements a finalizer.
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);      
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // If you need thread safety, use a lock around these 
    // operations, as well as in your methods that use the resource.
    if (!_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            if (DC != null)
                DC.Dispose();
        }

        // Indicate that the instance has been disposed.
        DC = null;
        _disposed = true;   
    }
}
```